# Handling clicks on multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and want to write efficient jQuery code.

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var tmp = 0; tmp < divs.length; tmp++) {
    divs[i].onclick = handleDivClicks;
}

var divID;
var zoneID;
var y = 0;

function handleDivsClicks(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "divOne") {
        x = obj.setLength(function() {
        showMsgInDiv("Length");
    }, 2000);
    showMsgInDiv("Length Set");
    } 
    else if (e.target.id == "divTwo") {
        obj.clearLength(divID);
        showMsgInDiv("Length Cleared");
    } 
    else if (e.target.id == "divThree") {
        zoneID = obj.setZone(function() {
        showMsgInDiv("Zone Set. Ctr: " + y++);
    }, 2000);
}
```

All these are custom functions and I have not declared them in this post. I just want to find out how concise and efficiently can the above code be written in jQuery

Comment: I think it's a good idea to attach a handler to several events

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').click(handleDivsClicks);
```

Simple.  Isn't jQuery nice?

Comment: Smart! and what about code in handledivclicks. Can that be written in jquery t00

Comment: @RussT: The only thing in `handleDivsClicks` that can be changed to use jQuery would be `e.target.id`.  That could be written as `$(e.target).attr('id')`, but `e.target.id` may be faster (as it doesn't need to run the jQuery function).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').bind('click', function(e){

   //.. your function code goes here

});
```

also don't forget that events propagate upwards through the DOM. So if all your divs are under one parent it should be possible just to bind the event handler to that parent i.e.

```
$('#divParent').bind('click', function(e){

   //.. your function code goes here

});
```

Comment: It's `bind('click'` not `.bind('onclick'`.

Comment: @Rocket. Oops. Thanks for not voting me down on that one. It would have been legit. I did know that (honest)

Comment: Or even better `.on('click'` since 1.7 :) http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

Comment: @CrabBucket: No prob.  I don't down-vote people unless their answer is completely wrong :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    var div_id = $(this).attr("id");

    if (div_id == "divOne") {
        x = obj.setLength(function(){
          showMsgInDiv("Length");
        }, 2000);
      showMsgInDiv("Length Set");
    }else if(div_id == "divTwo"){
        obj.clearLength(divID);
        showMsgInDiv("Length Cleared");
    }else if(div_id == "divThree"){
        zoneID = obj.setZone(function() {
        showMsgInDiv("Zone Set. Ctr: " + y++);
       }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to user jQuery try this using id selector to find the elements on the page and attach `click` handler this way. And instead of `if/else` conditions switch case is much better.

```
$("#divOne, #divTwo, #divThree").click(function(e){
    switch(e.target.id){
        case "divOne": 
           x = obj.setLength(function() {
               showMsgInDiv("Length");
            }, 2000);
           showMsgInDiv("Length Set");
           break;
        case "divTwo":
           obj.clearLength(e.target.id);
           showMsgInDiv("Length Cleared");
           break;
        case "divThree":
           zoneID = obj.setZone(function() {
              showMsgInDiv("Zone Set. Ctr: " + y++);
           }, 2000);
    }
});
```